# How to find a particular Div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Please guide me how can I find a particular div using jQuery for following html -

```
       <div class="tab_container">
            <div id="tabs-1111" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
                <p>26 High Street, Slough, SL1 1EP</p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-1110" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <div id="GoogleMap_Canvas" 
                    style="width: 410px; height: 450px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
```

I want to check if first div with 'tab_content' class contains div with id = 'GoogleMap_Canvas' or not - which should come out to be false for above html as it is in second div.

I tried using -

```
if ($(".tab_content:first").children('#GoogleMap_Canvas').length > 0)
or
if ($(".tab_content:nth-child(1)").children('#GoogleMap_Canvas').length> 0)
```

which seems to be working fine for me.

However, I am confused why following jQuery returns null?

```
($(".tab_content")[1]).children('#GoogleMap_Canvas') //returns null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are checking for a unique id, this doesn't need to be that complicated.

```
if ($('#GoogleMap_Canvas').length > 0)
  //map div exists
```

I believe you are getting a null because you are calling .children on a non-jquery object.  Try this:

```
$($(".tab_content")[1]).children('#GoogleMap_Canvas')
```

or better:

```
$(".tab_content:eq(1)").children('#GoogleMap_Canvas')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jQuery's [has selector](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to get you the 'tab_content' div that contains the 'GoogleMap_Canvas' div:

```
var googleDivContainer = $(".tab_content").has('#GoogleMap_Canvas');
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns NULL

```
($(".tab_content")[1]).children('#GoogleMap_Canvas')
```

because $(".tab_content")[1] returns a DOM element which doesn't have a children method.

Add an extra "$" to cast the result to a jQuery object

```
$($(".tab_content")[1]).children('#GoogleMap_Canvas')
```

Answer (score 1):

"I want to check if first div with 'tab_content' class contains div with id = 'GoogleMap_Canvas' or not"

use this:

```
if ($(".tab_container").children('.tab_content:first').children('#GoogleMap_Canvas').length > 0){
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line returns `null` because `$(".tab_content")[1]` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object, and DOM elements do not expose a `children()` method.

Note that [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns a jQuery object, so the following code would work:

```
var children = $(".tab_content").eq(1).children('#GoogleMap_Canvas');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var length = $(".tab_content[id*='GoogleMap_Canvas']").length;
```