# How can I add/remove element/s by coords from array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, coords

I would like to know a way to get coordinates from array, check if element exist at these `coords` and create it if it doesn't.

This is for an upcoming `nodejs` game. I have tried a couple of techniques, but all ends with a nested code and overall slow performance

For the sake of this question let's assume I have this array of objects or it can also comes from a `json` file doesn't really matter as long as it works as expected.

```
{
 id: 1,
 left: 60,
 top: 10,
 free: 1
},
 id:2 ,
 left: 120,
 top: 10:,
 free: 0
}
```

And I have a simple container like so

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 300px; background: red;"></div>
```

Now imagine a grid of 5 in-line `60x50` boxes where id:1 is the first box and id:2 is the 2nd box. How can I check if element/div exist in the grid box 1 or 2 and if there is any, update free: to 1(exist) or 0(doesn't exist) in the array for the specific id?

Comment: I think you got this the other way around: from your question, it seems that the UI (the HTML / divs) is the source of truth, and the "model" needs to be updated if certain HTML elements are present. Usually is the opposite: the model dictate how the HTML should be rendered; you modify the model and the HTML should reflect the new state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution i can think of is, put an Id inside a div when rendering like for example, you have id=1,2 in your json and you have 5 boxes in your view, inside each box if you render a div, give it an id and then use jquery to find a div like here : [How to find a particular Div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067903/how-to-find-a-particular-div-using-jquery)

Or if you cannot put id on div, put a id on the top element(supposing it is div) of the box, find the box and try finding the required div inside that box element div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Or if you cannot put id on div, put a id on the top element(supposing it is div) of the box, find the box and try finding the required div inside that box element div." that combined with jquery find div method did the job perfectly. I just had to adjust some stuff, but yeah it works pretty well now. Thank you.